# Are the yellow roof buildings inns?

Tags: carcassonne

In the new 2015 edition of Carcassonne Inns and Cathedrals, there are yellow roof buildings on some of the road pieces. Are these inns?

[image: yellow roofed building in question]

Answer (score 12):

No, that's just scenery. The inns all have lakes next to them.

[This copy of the rules](http://www.zmangames.com/uploads/4/7/1/7/47170931/en-carcassonnne-ii-ext1-rules.pdf) appears to be for the new edition (it says ©2002, 2015 and it doesn't look quite like my copy of the original edition) and the inns all have an obvious lake right next to them. For example:

[image]

Comment: I noticed in that particular example they give there is a lake next to that inn, but they don't mention in the rules that the inns are denoted by lakes, so how do you know for sure?

Comment: @spacetyper Those rules give at least five examples of tiles with inns, and they look the same every time: red roof, inn on the top side of the lake. They're also essentially the same in the old edition as well, different art style but still always red roof and lake. And [the old edition of the rules](http://www.world-of-board-games.com.sg/docs/Carcassonne-Inns-Cathedrals.pdf) actually referred to it as an "Inn on the Lake".

Comment: @Cascabel Not every inn has a red roof, for example one of the tiles in River II (2E). See my question about it: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/59653/30400