# Does this tile from River II have an Inn?

Tags: carcassonne, carcassonne-river

This tile from the River II expansion (included in Count, King & Robber) have an inn on the road?

It has a lake like the other inns from Inns & Cathedrals, but not the signature red roof. This leaves quite a bit of ambiguity about what defines an inn.

[image: River tile]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn’t investigate far enough as Zibelas correctly pointed out.

“This expansion features a River II tile with an inn. Unlike other inns, this one has a yellow roof:” https://wikicarpedia.com/car/Inns_and_Cathedrals

[image: Yellow Roof Inn]

Original post:

Wikicarpedia’s Count, King & Robber section calls this a farm house.

[image: Farm House]

https://wikicarpedia.com/car/Count,_King_and_Robber

Comment: I don't think that is correct since the exact tile is listed as Inn under the tile section of your linked article

Comment: Thank you, I presume WikiCarpedia is official in its rulings

Comment: Yes. “The CAR represents the final word of Hans im Glück (HiG), the original German publisher, and we encourage use of the rules found here for consistency worldwide.” https://wikicarpedia.com/car/Wikicarpedia:About